# Attaching Custom Networks with Podman Containers

Tags: networking, docker, podman

I am working with Podman and I want to run a simple Nginx container. I want to run the container in an isolated custom network similar to Docker.

The command is as follows:

```shell
docker run -it -p 8080:80 --net my-custom-net nginx
```

I have tried something similar with Podman. Everything is working fine, but I am unable to attach a custom network like I can in Docker.

I am hoping for a solution or workaround to attach a custom network in Podman.

```shell
podman run -it -p 8080:80 --net my-custom-net nginx
```

But till now I found that `--network or --net` takes mode like,

```shell
podman run -it -p 8080:80 --net bridge|host nginx
```

How do I attach the custom network that I have created using the `podman network create` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option for Podman is `--network`, just like with Docker:

```
$ podman network create my-custom-net
my-custom-net
$ podman network inspect my-custom-net | jq '.[].subnets[].subnet'
"10.89.2.0/24"
$ podman run --rm -it --network=my-custom-net busybox sh
/ # ip addr show eth0
2: eth0@if4: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP,M-DOWN> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue qlen 1000
    link/ether 4a:8d:17:ae:03:e2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.89.2.7/24 brd 10.89.2.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::488d:17ff:feae:3e2/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: I am running this command
```podman run --rm -it --network=my-custom-net -p 3000:80 docker.io/nginx```
Then why `curl localhost:3000` not giving any response ?

Comment: That exact commands works correctly for me (`curl localhost:3000` results in the `Welcome to nginx!` document). Have you configured any custom firewall rules that might be blocking the connection?

Comment: Solved, I was using previous version of Podman that were creating issues.